# Batch file to conditionally copy items from one text to other

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy from file1.txt to file2.txt only if file1.txt have additional lines that are not already present in file2.txt.

say, file1.txt is as below.

```
*createbutton(5,5,0,6,BUTTON,"",EvalTcl,"Bolt.tcl")
*createbutton(5,"Help",5,6,4,BUTTON,"",EvalTcl,"help.tcl")
*createbutton(5,newline)
```

and file2.txt is as below

```
*createbutton(5,5,0,6,BUTTON,"",EvalTcl,"Bolt.tcl")
*createbutton(5,"Help",5,6,4,BUTTON,"",EvalTcl,"help.tcl")
```

Then it should only copy line number 3 in file1.txt i.e.."*createbutton(5,newline)" to file2.txt, because the 1st 2 lines are already there in file2.txt.

I hope i am clear on my requirement.Any help is welcome.

Thank you,
Regards,
Prasad Poduval

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file=%~1"
set "line=%file%.line"
set "deduped=%file%.deduped"
::Define a variable containing a linefeed character
set LF=^


::The 2 blank lines above are critical, do not remove
>"%deduped%" (
for /f usebackq^ eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in ("%file%") do (
set "ln=%%A"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>"%line%" (echo !ln:\=\\!)
>nul findstr /xlg:"%line%" "%deduped%" || (echo !ln!)
endlocal
)
)
>nul move /y "%deduped%" "%file%"
2>nul del "%line%"
```

Comment: Please show some code you've tried. StackOverflow is not a place to come with a "requirement" and no code.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is essentially exactly what the [diff utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) does.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('type q25162700_1.txt^|findstr /g:q25162700_2.txt /v ') DO (
 >>q25162700_2.txt ECHO %%a
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used files named `q25162700_1.txt` and `q25162700_2.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Comment: Sorry Magoo, but this isn't working. I have used the a code from Dbenham, used to delete repeated rows(pls check above in the post) in a user input file,and tried to manipulate it a bit, but nthing is working.